# Biased but consistent estimator for the mean of Gaussian distribution?

Tags: distributions, estimation, point-estimation

$(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is a random sample from $\mathrm{N}(θ, 1)$. We know sample mean is a unbiased estimator that is consistent. What would be a biased but consistent estimator for θ? Would it be sample median? If so, can anyone prove that?

Comment: Any estimator of the form,

$$\tilde \theta = \bar X + o(n)$$
like for example,


$$\tilde \theta = \bar X + \frac an$$

with $a$ a finite fixed number,

is a biased but consistent estimator. The question is why do you want if for?

Comment: The sample median is an unbiased estimator for the population mean at the normal ($E\left(\stackrel{\sim}{X}\right)=\theta)$).